# Correct terminology for animated characters for iPhone game

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, graphics

I have a guy on freelancer.com that is doing my art for me for my iphone game. Well, I need a 3d character similar to temple run (but does a bunch of other stuff) for my game. I know this guy is really good at 2d and 3d animation, but whenever i try to explain what i need, he says things like, "thats cool, could you please show me the game, that way it would be easier for me to make your video." Im just a little nervous that he doesnt understand what i need. I need a character with several short animation loops, not a 'video'.  The guy is also from india, so I think is english is kind of bad and he may not fully understand me. What can i say in terminology to get him to understand what i need. Im pretty sure what im looking for is a 'sprite'? but what is this, can someone just please give me some terms to explain my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology you could be looking for might be "sprite", like in the game "Donkey Kong" where pre-rendered 3D animations are converted to 2D animations.

Comment: wait, but is a sprite still for 3d also?

Comment: As Wikipedia describes it a sprite is a "two-dimensional image or animation that is integrated into a larger scene." So it's really a graphical overlay. The choice to use sprites should be based on what you want the mechanics of the game to be. If the 3D model will only be seen from the top, you don't need to waste valuable processing power rendering the animations when a pre-rendered "top" animation gives the same output.

Comment: Always remember. Google is your friend. What your asking has probably been an issue for someone else at some point in time. The wikipedia page for sprites has a good section devoted to 3D sprites here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)#Move_to_3D

Comment: this is a question in response to what you just said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875678/is-this-a-3d-or-2d-character-for-iphone-game

Comment: Lastly, looking through your previous questions I can see your having a few issues. I'd recommend looking at the UDK game kit to use as a framework for your game creation, at least for the first project. The documentation is solid and there's a strong community behind it so you'll be able to learn and progress at a faster pace.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite is probably a safe bet. Even if it isn't the iOS standard, people will understand you because it's a widely-used convention.