# Is this a 3d or 2d character for iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, animation, graphics

I'm making an iphone game, and need some graphics for it. I was wondering if the graphics I need are considered 2d or 3d. I only a few distinct actions, My character isnt going to be rotating at the users interaction. Basically, If you can imagine a checker board, I need my character to be seen to be able move forward, turn right and move forward, and turn left and move forward. So basically just move on that checkerboard in all directions on a birds eye view. Yet, when he is moving backwards (or really facing 180 degrees and moving forwards) I need him to be able to see his face, I dont want him to face the front and literally walk backwards. So, is this a 3d job or a 2d job? And would this be considered a sprite or what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites would be the best answer for you. If you look at old RTS games you'll notice that they are in fact sprites and not true 3D models. This was to allow for a greater number on on screen entities. Working on your previous question. Ask your designer for 3D models and then output it as a 2D gif. You may even want to look at swapping between sprites and proper 3D model in game to accomplish what your asking instead of committing to just one method.

Lastly, Instead of opening up a new question it would be better to edit your previous one. This stops duplicate entries from accumulating and is just a little bit neater. I'd also recommend going on the [UDK forums](http://forums.epicgames.com/forums/366-UDK) or even a stack-exchange sister site devoted to 3D/Game Dev (I haven't checked but there should be one). Even if your not using the UDK framework it's good to check out the community to learn more.

Comment: so i guess i should ask for a 3d walk cycle?

Comment: That would be the best option. If you then get the 3D model you can output it how you want, to better suit the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a 3D one. Considering you want to have a Bird-Eye view (the view you use in 3rd view rpg games I presume) on the character and so your not going to look at it by a side view that can be implemented with a sprite.

Another point is the final product that would be considerately better with a low poly, well skinned 3D model.